# My Italian driving licence is about to expire, how to renew it in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

My driving licence is about to expire, I read time ago how to exchange it with a UK driving licence, is the process different for the renewal instead?

Comment: Of course the process is different. The process of exchanging for a UK license requires dealing with UK authorities, who are not able to renew your Italian license. To renew your Italian license, you have to deal with Italian authorities.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, or maybe I'm just confused. Does exchange implies a new "expiring date" on your license?

Comment: *Exchange* means you get a new UK license, in exchange for your Italian license, which you will give up.  *Renew* means you get a new Italian license, for which, according to SztupY, you aren't actually eligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a resident in the UK, then you won't be able to renew your Italian licence and keep it as Italian, you have to exchange it to a UK one. This is [global to all EU countries](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-renewal-exchange/index_en.htm):

> If you move to another EU country and the validity of your EU driving licence expires, you will have to renew your licence in the country where you are normally resident

When you exchange the licence they will actually send you a new one, with the original categories from your old licence, but with a new validity date. In the UK this is usually for 10 years, unless you are nearing 70 years old.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about renewing an Italian license instead of exchanging it for a UK license.

Comment: @phoog I thought OP was worrying about the end date of the licence after an exchange, but added notes

Comment: Is the inability to renew based in Italian law (because the driver is no longer resident in Italy), or is it simply that the driver, being a UK resident, is not allowed to drive in the UK with an Italian license?  Or is there some EU rule in play?

Comment: Driving licences in the EU (and some other countries) are tied to residency and not other factors

Comment: @SztupY , Yes I was worried about the expiring date of the new licence. So, as you said, exchanging implies a new expiring date.